# Nativescript with node js Cloudinary modules

Tags: nativescript, cloudinary

I am trying to upload my images to Cloudinary using the Cloudinary's node.js module.
The problem is that Cloudinary depends on "crypto" module that is present in node.js environment as a global property and in NativeScript, of course, it isn't.

I tried:

- installing crypto manually with `npm install crypto --save` and moving it into node_modules/cludinary/node_modules to no avail
- I manually changed every reference to crypto in node_modules/cloudinary from `crypto = require('crypto');` to `crypto = require('./crypto');` to no availtoo :(

The question is how can add global dependencies of a pure node.js module in NativeScript?

**EDIT**

For those looking for a "perfect" solution. In the end I am POSTing base64 version of the image to an endpoint on our server where I use Cloudinary library (GEM) to communicate with Cloudinary service. Since I have to go through my server anyway to save references to the new image there is no overhead that this approach brings...

Comment: crypto is currently not supported by {N} - you can track this issue  https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/195 for more information on that matter

Comment: Since it's an open source library, you can always remove this dependency and suggest another one to replace it. Basically it's used to generate a SHA-1 based signature and random strings for some of the functionalities.

Comment: Yes, I could fork the module and make the changes... In the end I decided to POST my pictures to my own server in base64 encoding and from there I use server based GEM/library to save it in Cloudinary. Thank you anyway ;)